# Angularjs Style/highlight code block within ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, ng-bind-html

In an effort to learn Angualr.js, I'm trying to collect a Wordpress post, using the plugin WP REST API and display it on a template in its correct format. I've got the post displaying the correct way using sanitize and ng-bind-html.

[image]

However, there are code blocks that I had originally highlighted (using WP Code Prettify) within the post. For example:

[image]

The question is how do I get the original post to look just like the image above, using ng-bind-html? Or is there another, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: It already should - Are the styles inline or if you are using external stylesheet, check why its not being applied.

Comment: They are being displayed correctly apart from one issue. There's double quotes around the markup inside the pre tags? This is preventing the WP Code Prettify from styling the markup

Comment: DId you check if the data in the bind itself is containing the quotes?

Comment: For the above example, part of the data i'm getting back is as follows: <pre class=\"prettyprint linenums\">\r\n&#47;&#47; Handlebars template\r\n&lt;script id=&#34;location-template&#34; type=&#34;text&#47;x-handlebars-template&#34;&gt;&lt;&#47;script&gt;\r\n<\/pre> I don't think there are quotes within it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try using $sce to mark the post content as trusted.

Example:

```
    .controller('CtrlName', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $http.get('wp-json/pages/pageSlug').success(function(res){
        $scope.page = res;
        $scope.page.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(res.content);
    });
})
```